# update in same method after session is closed in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

In hibernate,we have written a method.I open a session do a save operation the closed the session.If I want to do update operation in same method after closing the session.is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Without open session its not possible to create/update records in hibernate. Internally when you close hibernate session it terminates connection with the database.

Always apply following way of coding in while developing around hibernate

```
try{
//open session
}catch(ex){
}
finally{
//close session
}
```

All the database create/update should be after opening session and before closing session.

Thanks,
Gaurav